# SSH server on Windows Xp Embedded

Tags: ssh, windows-xp

I'm trying to run an SSH server on Windows Xp Embedded.
I've tried all open-source/freeware flavours so far that I know (openSSH for Windows, CopSSH, FreeSSHD, MobaSSH. All of them tell me they are installed succesfully, but the SSH service never starts, it always tells the service terminated unexpectedly. No ssh server logs are being created either.

Anyone who got the same or knows the reason behind it?
It's probably a component that's missing in the XPe Installation, but it's hard to find out which one without more detailed error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this isn't an XP Embedded image you created using the Embedded Toolkit.  With XP Embedded, you don't install the software using an install package.  You stream it into the image during creation.  That said, you need to look for applications that don't need to be installed.  Here is [PuTTY Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/putty_portable) and you can probably use the *Running from a CD (PuTTY Portable Live)* instructions to generate something that will run for you.  If you poke around the site you can probably find other live applications that you can run.

Comment: Hello Larry, thanks for your answer. The XPe image was created by someone else, but it was made with the embedded toolkit (or whatever the builder is called). Ofcourse, there are always applications that are installed afterwards (anti-virus, updated software, etc.) I'm a bit confused about your propasal to use PuTTY. Correct me if I'm wrong, but PuTTy is a client application, not a server, so I'm not sure how to use it as a SSH server application?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point of your question and assumed you wanted to connect to an SSH server rather than run one.  Let me try again.